# Probability of getting 1

Tags: probability

A six faced fair dice is thrown untill 1 comes , then the probability that 1 comes in even number of trials is .

In this I am not getting any start as what could be the sample space

Can anybody provide me a hint .

Comment: answer is given as 5/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that it occurs in $2k$ times is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$, hence then probability that it occurs in even times is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{36}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k=\frac{5}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}} = \frac{5}{11}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an infinite series (geometric), or you could avoid this by observing that in order to throw a $1$ after an *even* number of trials, you want:

- no $1$ at the first trial, but possibly one on the second;
- if there's no $1$ during the *first two* trials, it **starts all over again**.

Call the probability of needing an even number of trials $p$, then:
$$p = \mbox{"no 1 on trial 1"} \cdot \mbox{"a 1 on trial 2"} + \mbox{"no 1 on trial 1"} \cdot \mbox{"no 1 on trial 2"} \cdot p$$

Can you plug in the probabilities and find $p$? Hoover over for the next step:

> $\displaystyle p = \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2p \implies p = \ldots$

Note that this leads to a simple linear equation in $p$...!